# Maps Restaurant List Scrape

Tags: python, selenium, screen-scraping

I'am attempting to scrape the Restaurant List in a city from googlemaps using python selenium,  however, I'am unable to extract the elements (restaurant names) with the code I tried.

Using the inspect element, I click on the restaurant title, this is the element details:

```
h3 class="section-result-title"> 

span jstcache="126">Amrutha Lounge</span> 

button jstcache="127" style="display:none"></button> </h3>
```

I want to extract the restaurant names, in the above element, it is `'Amrutha Lounge'`.

Second Restaurant Element(Bright):

```
h3 class="section-result-title"> 


span jstcache="126">Bright</span> 


button jstcache="127" style="display:none"></button> </h3>
```

I have tried extracting the names through the code I have written below, however, so far unsuccessfully.

```
from selenium import webdriver

driver= 
webdriver.Chrome(executable_path="C:/users/usr/Desktop/chromedriver.exe")

UrlA = "https://www.google.com/maps/search/"
UrlB= "London"
UrlC="Restaurants"
UrlD= UrlA + UrlB + '+' + UrlC
driver.get(UrlD)

x=driver.find_elements_by_class_name('section-result-title')
print(x)
```

This is the output I am currently getting:

```
selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.WebElement (session="db301e2fc353297f0e9799b9a5fefd2f", element="c39f1e01-0795-4423-8b1e-61ee5b4e5048")>, <selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.WebElement (session="db301e2fc353297f0e9799b9a5fefd2f", element="39e7a7e7-2dae-4638-9664-391f3a00dcb7"
```

This is the output i want to get:

```
Amrutha Lounge

Bright

Bagatelle London

...
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are printing the `WebElement`. You need to print the `String`.

As you are already storing the list of WebElements in variable `x`. You can simply iterate over them and print the `.text` of `WebElement` to get the text

https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/api.html#selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.WebElement.text

So Just change your code to

```
for elm in x:
    print(elm.text)
```